# In 2.92 how do I show the 3D cursor in 2D drawing mode?

Tags: 2d, 3d-cursor

I am trying to rotate a stroke object in 3D space, but I need to rotate at the 3D cursor.  In 2D mode, you never see the 3D cursor, and clicking the 'cursor' Icon doesn't display anything. I can see the location of the 3D cursor is changing in the View details, but I can't see it anywhere in any view.

To reproduce start with a new 2D Drawing, then rotate the view with the number pad and 4,6,8 or 2.

Is there a way to turn the cursor back on???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to Viewport Overlays > 3D Cursor

[image]